# About Oracle performance (Multi-SELECT + Single COUNT() vs Single-SELECT + Multi COUNT() )

Tags: oracle, count, multi-select, date-conversion, to-char

Which is better(for only speed) way?

1. Single SELECT (Multi COUNT(), Multi TO_CHAR())

```
SELECT
    T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') RG_DATE, COUNT(T.UUID) VISITS
FROM
    ACCOUNT T
GROUP BY
    T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
HAVING 
    COUNT(T.UUID) > 0
```

> EDIT
>
> ```
> SELECT
>   T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') RG_DATE, COUNT(T.UUID) VISITS
> FROM
>   ACCOUNT T
> GROUP BY
>   T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
> HAVING 
>   COUNT(T.UUID) > 0
>   AND COUNT(T.UUID) >= 2       -- Spring mybatis generated code
>   AND COUNT(T.UUID) < 5        -- Spring mybatis generated code
> ```

2. Double SELECT (Single COUNT(), Multi TO_CHAR())

```
SELECT
    T.UUID, T.RG_DATE, T.VISITS
FROM (
    SELECT
        T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') RG_DATE, COUNT(T.UUID) VISITS
    FROM
        ACCOUNT T
    GROUP BY
        T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ) T
WHERE
    T.VISITS > 0
```

3. Multi SELECT (Single COUNT(), Single TO_CHAR())

```
SELECT
    T.UUID, T.RG_DATE, T.VISITS
FROM (
    SELECT
        T.UUID, T.RG_DATE, COUNT(T.UUID) VISITS
    FROM (
        SELECT
            T.UUID, TO_CHAR(T.RG_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') RG_DATE
        FROM
            ACCOUNT T
        ) T
    GROUP BY
        T.UUID, T.RG_DATE
    ) T
WHERE
    T.VISITS > 0
```

I've test this in small db and the difference is very small, so I can't decide which is the best one.
How about large(maybe giant) db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle optimizer will transform 3rd query to the equal to 2nd (subquery view merging transformation), so they will have equal plans by default.

First one is better: `having` will be executed as a filter of `group-by` operation. If you compare execution plans, you will see the difference.

I'd suggest to use `trunc(rg_date)` instead of to_char with proper nls_date_format.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.
As you can see, condition of `having` is `> 0` and this can be ignorable(even if `VISITS` is zero, this is an extremely little probability).
Function `COUNT()` and `TO_CHAR()` (also `TRUNC()`) duplicates in `SELECT , WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING` clauses.
Because of this, I think 1st one is not the best way. Am I wrong?

Comment: 1. If uuid is nullable, you can't ignore the having condition, otherwise it will not be equal to the original query. 2. It doesn't matter if you specify functions in select-list and group-by or in the inner subquery (which will be merged/unnested). Look at the column `projection` of plans. They show on which steps oracle calculates them.

Comment: I see. One more question, I saw functions like `COUNT()` are repeating  its execution in results of plan. It takes a long time (complexity of `O(N)`) for `COUNT()` results, doesn't it? The repeating functions can be ignored for performance?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly. What do you mean by "functions like count are repeating its execution in results of plan"?   The same `count()` in the different clauses of single group-by will be calculated just once in group-by operation. Just Check plans

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was my mistake. The query I'd tested is a bit complicated than above query I wrote. `HAVING` clause can have several conditions. I've just updated it.

Comment: @codingmonster ok, I see you have 3 predicates, but still oracle calculates `COUNT(UUID)` just once.

Comment: I'm sorry, that I annoyed you. I think I have to learn about PLAN of Oracle more and more. Thank you

Comment: @codingmonster no problem at all, I like people who love to learn more about it :) Oracle CBO is a most powerful database optimizer with a lot of very cool features!  I'd suggest to read "CBO fundamentals" by Jonathan Lewis. It's a *must-read* for Oracle specialists.